# How to send POST data as JSON in Android Retrofit2 and read them in PHP?

Tags: php, android, kotlin, post, retrofit2

I'm trying to send data in Android Kotlin with Retrofit2 (as JSON), but although the request has sent correctly (I see it in App Inspector and data are sent correctly as JSON), PHP cannot read them.
I send the code, both Android Kotlin and PHP.

I read many questions on Stackoverflow and external, but I haven't fixed the issue yet

PHP:

```
$post = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

(I tried to put the flag "true" as well, but nothing is changed)

(this is empty, I printed it with "foreach" and it doesn't return anything)

Kotlin:
(ExamplePostList:)

```
data class ExamplePostList(
@SerializedName("user")
val userid: String
)
```

(ApiInterface:)

```
interface ApiInterface {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8")
    @POST("example/post")
    fun postExampleInfo(
        @Body post: ExamplePostList
    ): Call<PostResponseList>
}
```

(ApiClient:)

```
object ApiClient {
var BASE_URL: String = "https://example.com/api/v1/"
val client: ApiInterface
    get() {
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
        val httpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(httpClient)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build()

        return retrofit.create(ApiInterface::class.java)
    }
}
```

and in my MainActivity I try to send the request:

```
fun sendExample() {
    val call: Call<PostResponseList> =
        ApiClient.client.postExampleInfo(
            post = ExamplePostList(
                userid = "example"
            )
        )
    call.enqueue(object : Callback<PostResponseList> {

        override fun onResponse(
            call: Call<PostResponseList>?,
            response: Response<PostResponseList>?
        ) {
            println("Response:\n" + response!!.body()!!)
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<PostResponseList>?, t: Throwable?) {
            Log.v("Error", t.toString())
        }

    })
}
```

Comment: Well what do you get if you log or print or echo file_get_contents('php://input')? Check what you get.

Comment: Nothing, empty. This is the weird thing